# HomeAssistant cancel a callback in AppDaemon

Tags: python, home-assistant

I'm running HomeAssistant with AppDaemon and have written an AppDaemon app to control my lights. I use the `self.run_in(...)` function which is (as described in documentation) calling a call back and returning a handler so that it can be canceled.

I'm having a problem finding information on how to cancel the callback with the help of the handler.

AppDaemon API documenation for `run_in`: https://appdaemon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/AD_API_REFERENCE.html#run-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why I missed it, but it was right here in the documentation: https://appdaemon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/AD_API_REFERENCE.html#appdaemon.adapi.ADAPI.cancel_timer